# How can I create individual objects in a for loop in Java?

Tags: java

I have a MyData class representing an input of strings, which I also added to a list and parsed individually into an array.

```
class MyData{
    private String data1;
    private String data2; 
    private int data3; 
    
    public MyData(String d1, String d2, int d3){
        this.data1=d1; 
        this.data2=d2;
        this.data3=d3;
    }
    //getter and setter
    }
    
    String str1="IRC00001 blue 2017";
    String str2="IRC00002 red 2019";
    String str3="IRC00003 black 2020";
    
    List<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add(str1);
    list.add(str2);
    list.add(str3);
    
    for(String s:list) {
    String[] parts=s.split(" ");
    String number=parts[0];
    String colour=parts[1];
    String y=parts[2];
    int year=Integer.parseInt(y);
```

I am trying to create a MyData object for each String in a for loop, this is necessary because there is a large number of strings (not in this example) and the user won't be able to initialize each of them individually. However when I try to use them they all have been overwritten by the last entry of the list. Is there a way to initialize each object in a loop, and if yes, how can I name a variable for each of them?

I'm sorry if this question has been asked multiple times. I just could't find a way to make it work on my example.

````
```
List<MyData>myList=new ArrayList<MyData>();

for(String string1:list) {
    myList.add(new MyData(number,colour,year));

}

for(MyData data:myList) {
    System.out.print(data.getYear());
}

//prints:
//2020 2020 2020
````

Comment: Your variables never change in the for loop that adds to the list. They should be assigned and used in the same loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, I guess this points in the same direction as the code sample below. You are both right and it has worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SOF {
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    SOF s= new SOF();
    s.test();
}

public void test(){ 
    String str1 = "IRC00001 blue 2017";
    String str2 = "IRC00002 red 2019";
    String str3 = "IRC00003 black 2020";

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add(str1);
    list.add(str2);
    list.add(str3);

    List<MyData> myList = new ArrayList<MyData>();

    for (String s : list) {
        String[] parts = s.split(" ");
        String number = parts[0];
        String colour = parts[1];
        String y = parts[2];
        int year = Integer.parseInt(y);
        myList.add(new MyData(number, colour, year));
    }


    for (MyData data : myList) {
        System.out.print(" "+ data.getData3());
    }

}
}

class MyData{
private String data1;
private String data2;
private int data3;

public MyData(String d1, String d2, int d3){
    this.data1=d1;
    this.data2=d2;
    this.data3=d3;
}

public String getData1() {
    return data1;
}

public void setData1(String data1) {
    this.data1 = data1;
}

public String getData2() {
    return data2;
}

public void setData2(String data2) {
    this.data2 = data2;
}

public int getData3() {
    return data3;
}

public void setData3(int data3) {
    this.data3 = data3;
}


}
```

output is : 2017 2019 2020

Comment: That tweak to my code has just worked for me too. Thank you that's great!